# Take n most records with aggregate

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need help constructing a linq query that will return a list of usernames that show up the most in a log table for specific messages.

```
public class Log
{
  public string Username {get; set;}
  public string Message {get; set;}
}
```

I'm interested in rows where message is either "Created User", "Modified User", or "Deleted User".

So far I have:

```
    public IQueryable<Log> GetTop5ActiveUsersByManagementMessages()
    {
        return this.ObjectContext.Logs
            .Where(w => w.Message == "Created User" || 
                   w.Message == "Removed User" || 
                   w.Message == "Updated User").Take(5);
    }
```

I want this to return the top 5 **usernames** based on the number or entries of these messages in the log table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use grouping to accomplish this task:

```
this.ObjectContext.Logs
        .Where(w => w.Message == "Created User" || 
               w.Message == "Removed User" || 
               w.Message == "Updated User")
        .GroupBy(w => w.Username)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
        .Select(g => g.Key)
        .Take(5);
```